# Label Doesn't Show on Panel (repaint and validate tried)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I've recently tried touching GUI programming, The concept is pretty simple actually. However I've encountered a small error. The JLabel added on my JPanel isn't showing. I've called Validate and Repaint but both aren't showing.

The code is using SWING and awt for event handling.

Here is the very quick code I've put together to replicate the issue:

```
    package com.first;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class wraith
    {
            public static void main(String[] arg)
            {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wraith, the game");
                            JPanel panel = new JPanel()
                            {

                                /**
                                 * 
                                 */
                                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                                @Override
                                public void paint(Graphics g) {
                                    super.paint(g);
                                    this.setBackground(new Color(0f,0f,0f,1.0f));
                                }   

                            };
                            JLabel label = new JLabel()
                            {

                                /**
                                 * 
                                 */
                                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                                @Override
                                public void paint(Graphics arg0) 
                                {
                                    super.paint(arg0);
                                    this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                                    this.setText("Width: " + frame.getWidth() + " Height: " + frame.getHeight());
                                    this.setHorizontalAlignment(LEFT);
                                    this.setVerticalAlignment(TOP);
                                }

                            };
                            frame.setSize(500, 500);
                            frame.add(panel);
                            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                            panel.add(label);
                            panel.validate();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        }

                    });
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't override a painting method to set properties on a component.

You create the component and then you set its properties:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("...");
label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
```

> How am I supposed to update my label

```
this.setText("Width: " + frame.getWidth() + " Height: " + frame.getHeight());
```

If you want to dynamically display the width/height of the frame then you should use a listener to notify the label of a change. In this case you would use a `ComponentListener` and handle the `componentResized(...)` method. So basically in the `componentResized(...)` method you use `label.setText(...)`, which means the label needs to be defined as an instance variable in your class.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) for example code to get you started.

Note, same advice for the JPanel. Don't override paint() just to set the background of the panel. Just invoke the setBackground() method after creating the panel.

Comment: @Delupara: because Rob Camick's one of the smartest Swing programmers around. 1+

Comment: I actually was unaware of complements listeners. I knew about action and windows listeners though thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the JLabel's paint method to create its text, it will not use that text to size itself, and the label's size will remain 0 x 0. For this reason, use the JLabel's `setText(...)` method for setting the text. You almost never want to override a Swing component's paint method regardless, and only occasionally will override the paintComponent method.

Comment: How am I supposed to update my label if I can't specify how to paint it then?

Comment: @Delupara: you update it by setting its text when you need to change it. You rarely paint directly on a JLabel, and certainly not how you're doing it.